# I have many problems after installing Gnome 3.10

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

I just tried to install Gnome 3.10 on my Ubuntu 13.10 and now my OS is totally destroyed. I am also seeing lots of lag. How can I revert it or install it correctly? I uninstalled it, but this did not help. Is there any way to easily switch between Unity and Gnome?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "my OS is totally destroyed"? Please try to *describe* the problems you're experiencing. If you can't be bothered to actually explain what's wrong, why should anyone here be bothered to help you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1) and then remove the configuration file ~/.config/dconf/user like this :

(this action will remove your gnome settings)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start
```

Hope this helps!